# Typescript - How to selection the overload function signature to get parameters types from?

Tags: typescript

Let's say a simple overloaded function defined as the following:

```js
function f(p: number) : string;
function f(p: string) : undefined;

function f(p: number | string): number | string {
    return (typeof p === 'number') ? String(p) : undefined;
}
```

`Parameters<typeof f>[0]` gives me only `string`. Because it's the last overload defined.

**How to choose which overload function to get the parameters from ?**
Without having to reorder the definitions of course.

Comment: [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#use-union-types) States to use Union types instead of duplicate overloads differing by param types

Comment: @AndrewNolan It also states `Note that we didn’t make b optional here because the return types of the signatures differ`. Like so, since mines have differents returns types, this is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rather use a generic function?

```
function f<K extends number | string>(p: K): K {
    return p;
}
```

Comment: No. The snippet I used was just to simplify the exemple. I updated